# Single pixel gap between images in SwiftUI HStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple View with a HStack that has two images side by side. These image end up rendering with a single pixel gap between the two.

How can I display these images exactly beside each other?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Image("left")
            Image("right")
        }
    }
}
```

**`left` & `right` images:**

[image: left]
[image: right]

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: have you tried `HStack(spacing: -1) ` or something similar, depending on the number of `pixels` between the images.

Comment: `spacing: 0` does it on mine...?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine doing this ends up chopping 1 pixels off of the end of the image (noticeable by looking at the diagonal lines)

Comment: @flanker which sdk and iOS version? I’m using Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.4 which shows the gap with spacing: 0 as shown in my screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Your **images are larger than the device's screen,** so it looks like they're moving out of the device's screen area. (I'm not sure why exactly, sorry)

- Rotate the screen and the empty space will disappear.
- I tried changing the size of the original images to [128x128], and the blank space disappeared.
- You can also fix this by changing the code to the following.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image("left")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()

                Image("right")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For this use case I wish for the images to overflow off the screen

Comment: If that's what you want, setting `spacing:` to negative is probably the best way to go for now. 
e.g.) `HStack(spacing: -1)` or `-0.0001`, both work.